# Is it possible to create a central glossary with doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I want to create and link to a central glossary using doxygen.

For creating the glossary, I would use a "glossary.md" file in my doxygen search path. The content is available through "related pages".

Would it be possible to link to entries in this glossary page from anywhere in my documentation?

Best regards
Andreas

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using the sections command and references onto them, but more elegant solutions would be welcome.

So my glossary.md file looks like:

```
@section GLOSSARY_ISR ISR
Interrupt service routine: ...
```

In my Doxyfile I added

```
ALIASES = "glos{1}=[\1](\ref GLOSSARY_\1)"
```

to be able to use a simple syntax from my code documentation as the following

```
Therefore an \glos{ISR} is used
```